# Random characters as return when useing libaws out of the sample

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, amazon-web-services, linker

I am trying to use [libaws](https://github.com/teltech/libaws) to use AWS-S3 server.
The testing application works perfect, but when I try to do my own application using this library it doesn't work.
The first issue, is with the function:

```
AWSConnectionFactory::getInstance()->getVersion();
```

I returns a string with the version of the library (0.9.3 in this case). 
The sample application shows "0.9.3" when I print it, but in my own application it shows different strings each time (with different sizes too). For example: "'K\217\214\377\2212A\244\242]  7\340m
P%A\240\355@"

I am using a mac (10.8) and xCode, and I am linking the library as static library.
Any sugestion?
Is there something wrong with the linking process?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.

There are two configuration flags in xCode to define the version of c++ libraries.
Into: "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++" -> "C++ Language dialect" and "C++ standard library".

When a project is generated using cMake, like in this case, those values are set as "Compiler Default".
But, xCode sets those values when a new project is generated, and those values are not "Compiler Default".

This difference changes the string definition (or something similar), and generates wrong answers.